# How can I insert data from my application to a BD with web service?

Tags: ios, swift, web-services

I have a problem with a web service to insert data in a database that is on my server, the problem is that I tried to run a web service with the following URL:

```
http://www.sitioWeb.mx/webs/registro.php?name=\(name.text!)&empres=\(empres.text!)&email=\(email.text!)&telefono=\(telefono.text.!)&event=\(event)
```

but it returns a "nil" value and my application stops, I do not know how I can send my information to insert it in my BD through a Web Service

I tried to run this web service as a query to a web service but still I get an error

```
let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler:{(data, response, error) -> Void in

            if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary{

                if let array = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "video") as? NSArray{
                    for tituloConvenios in array{
                        if let tituloC = tituloCon as? NSDictionary{

                            if let titulo = titulo.value(forKey: "titulo"){
                                self.arrayTituloV.append(titulo as! String)
                            }

                            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
                                self.listaVideos.reloadData()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }).resume()
```

If I use this code block, it gives me an error because it receives a nil in the request

Comment: The URL you've listed here isn't valid (for example, it includes `text. !`) Either this isn't your actual code, or you have mistakes there. Focus first on getting your URL correct without worrying about the `dataTask` call. If your `text` fields have parameters that require escaping, for example, this will all fail. Take a look at `URLComponents`. It probably is the tool you're actually looking for. There are a lot of `!`s here for things that can very easily fail (like network calls), so this code will tend to crash.

Comment: I'm sorry the error in the URL was because I miss the link

Comment: The posted link is still incorrect. Note the `.` between `text` and `!`. (I'm looking at the raw source because you've misformatted the URL in the question, so the backslashes are missing; please read over your question and make sure what we are reading matches your actual code.) But this doesn't change anything; your problem is that your URL when complete is not valid. Check what `urlString` actually evaluates to. (Also, there is no reason to use `NSURL` at all. Just use `URL`.

Comment: You were right, the problem is in my URL, a value I was sending was incorrect, thank you very much !!!